# Intellij idea cannot find existing class during rebuild (yet maven builds and project runs even from idea)

Tags: intellij-idea

I opened older project (which I left in state that it builds). Maven still builds externally. Running maven from idea builds (without delegate all actions to maven selected). Project runs and works.

Editor underline files claimed to be not existing, while they are existing. Rebuild complaints about the same. So I did all updates and all repairs, and dropping all cached and rebuild them, restarts. From editor pane point of view, all "errors" were cured by that. Maven still builds, app still runs, externally and from idea (do not build before run is not selected, so it does build it, and not via maven). SO idea *had to* build it *actually*, if it can run it. Yet still, rebuild project fails on not existence of one class. This class is definition of project root exception. This class indeed exists, just rebuild does not see it. And surprisingly, the rebuild process has no problem with all descendants of that exception. Descencant exceptions also "cannot be build", because their parent "does not exist", but descendants can be instantiated and used.

Java modules aren't used.

So the workaround is to build project using maven, don't use rebuild project, and then everything works. Yet it would be great if rebuild project could be used.

Any idea what could go wrong or what can I try to fix it?

Comment: Did you import project as Maven project? Please try to remove all IDE related data (.iml file and .idea folder) and reimport project again. Is it reproducible with some simplified project version?

Comment: not at the pc right now, will test later. The project worked, it get into this state by upgrading idea. The project was created from scratch in console, due to lacking of maven archetypes it was done by tearing-up some other project and once teared sufficiently, it was imported into idea. Other project wasn't affected by that. Will try reimport.

Comment: deleting the .idea directory fixed the rebuild, but broke syntax highlighting. Now it's all red everywhere, no class can be found when searching by name, while it's still all working :D But we know the drill, drop caches, reindex everything, and after that, it seems to be working. Funny thing. Is there a reason, why community version never suffer from this, while paid version feels like it's made from chinesium? Constantly breaking, requiring holding hand and fixing after every update?

Comment: ^^sorry for rant above, I need to work on myself some more. Thanks for suggesting me working fix.